# How can i setup Notification Bar Music Control widget in Geckoview Android

Tags: android, firefox, mozilla, gecko, geckoview

How can I setup music player widget in notification bar on Geckoview Android.

It is possible on chrome browser through Media Session Api

Below is the image from chrome browser android.

[image]

**How can I achieve similar music control widget on Geckoview?**

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement [`MediaSession.Delegate`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/MediaSession.Delegate.html) and then set it on your session using [`GeckoSession.setMediaSessionDelegate`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.html#setMediaSessionDelegate(org.mozilla.geckoview.MediaSession.Delegate)).

The [`onMetadata`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/MediaSession.Delegate.html#onMetadata(org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession,org.mozilla.geckoview.MediaSession,org.mozilla.geckoview.MediaSession.Metadata)) method inside `Delegate` gives you an instance of [`MediaSession`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/MediaSession.html) that you can use to respond to Android's media notification controls, e.g. to play the current media element you would just have to call [`mediaSession.play()`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/MediaSession.html#play()).